# How do I get the list of nodes allocated to the current job in SLURM?

Tags: slurm, hpc

I have a Software that requires a plain text list of nodes (once per task) where tasks are being sent. For example, if my job was launched with `-n 4 -c 1`, and I get 3 CPUs in `node1` and 1 CPU in `node2`, I'd like to get a file such as:

```
node1
node1
node1
node2
```

How can I get such a list?

I tried using:

```bash
scontrol show hostnames $SLURM_JOB_NODELIST
```

But this only works if ALL the tasks are assigned to separate nodes. In the example above, this would just result on:

```
node1
node2
```

So the Software would only send one task to each node, and underutilize the CPUs allocated in `node1`.

Thanks!
Miguel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest (though perhaps not most canonical) way is probably to run

```
srun hostname > hostfile
```

The file `hostfile` will contain the list of hostnames, with each hostname present as many times as the number of tasks that were allocated to that host.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `srun hostname >> hostfile`?

Answer (score 0):

You can usual use a combination of the information in the environment variables SLURM_JOB_CPUS_PER_NODE and SLURM_JOB_NODELIST within the job script to extract this information (though it does depend on the config of Slurm whether the first one contains the required information). By parsing and combining the information in the environment variables you should be able to get the format you require.

See:

https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html#lbAK